# Symfony call database from class object

Tags: php, service, doctrine-orm, symfony

On my symfony project I try to call doctrine from a class object, the idea is to put information into the database from the constructor of the object.

First, I must check if the object is already in the database, and if not, I must create the object and add it into the data base.
I do this from the class object because a lot a information are done in a single loop, and for optimization, I would like to do it from the object.

My object:

```
/** class object */
use MainBundle\Services\UserService;
use MainBundle\Entity\Item;
use MainBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class MyListObject{
    function MyListObject($data,$bddUser=null){
        if ($data->getSuccess()){
            foreach($data->getIdItem() as $id){
                $item = new IntItem($id,$data,$this);

                //database stuff
                $repository = $this->get('service.item');//get the table user from the database
                $existItem = $repository->getItemById($id);//get the item

                if ($existItem == null){
                    $itemBdd = new Item();
                    $itemBdd->setIditem($item->getId());
                    $itemBdd->setIdfull($item->getClassIdFull());
                    $itemBdd->setName($item->getName());


                }
```

My service:

```
services:
    service.item:
        class: MainBundle\Services\ItemService
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']
```

My service class:

```
<?

class ItemService
{

    private $entityManager;

    /*
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /*
     * @param integer $blogId
     *
     * @return Blog
     */
    public function getItemById($itemId)

        return $this->entityManager
                    ->getRepository('MainBundle:Item')
                    ->find($itemId);
    }
}
```

Then I got this error:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class "MainBundle\Object\MyListObject".
```

And after that I want to call doctrine again from my object to add the item to the database. I really don't know how I can fix that. all the injections I try haven't worked, I also try to extends controller, but I get another error.

Thanks.
*be nice with my english please, I have try my best !*

I really don't know where I go wrong

Answer (score 0):

your class should extend class ContainerAware

```
use \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class MyListObject extends ContainerAware
{
    public function someMethod() 
    {
        $this->container->get('service.item');
        ...
    }
}
```

like so you'll have access to the container and all its services.

Comment: this time I got this error : `Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object `

Comment: I already place it into a function. I am using symfony 3 so the ContainerAware is not avalable anymore. I use `use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;` that and also I implements `ContainerAwareInterface` and add a use `use ContainerAwareTrait;` inside the class

Answer (score 0):

Whith symfony 3

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;   

class ItemService implements ContainerAwareInterface
   {
       private $container;

       public function setcontainer(containerinterface $container = null)
       {
           $this->container = $container;
       }
   }
```